# Как заменить цвет PNG изображения?

Tags: python, изображения, pillow, png, pil

У меня есть изображение в формате png - [image]

Мне нужно заменить его цвет при помощи скрипта. Такой метод просто заливает всю форму цветом

```
image = Image.open(img_path)
image.paste(tuple(color), [0,0,image.size[0],image.size[1]])
image.save(f"{img.split('.', 1)[0]}-p.png")
```

Мне нужно залить цветом только те участки, на которых есть непрозрачные пиксели. Причём каждый пиксель нужно закрасить цветом той прозрачности, которая была у него до заполнения.

пример выходного изображения - [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем перебор пикселей и смотрим на те, у которых есть значение в альфаканале и заменяем их RGB на белый цвет

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/b547e08fc3935aee3cc24af58009643ffdde2e57/pil_pillow__examples/replace_rgb_by_alpha)

```
# pip install Pillow
from PIL import Image

image_file = "input.png"
img = Image.open(image_file).convert('RGBA')

pixdata = img.load()

for y in range(img.size[1]):
    for x in range(img.size[0]):
        alpha = pixdata[x, y][3]
        if alpha:
            pixdata[x, y] = (255, 255, 255, alpha)

img.save("output.png")
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]